# Controllers loaded from assembly in ASP NET CORE project cannot be found by swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I have an asp .net core console project that is loading an API assembly by using ApplicationPart. I need to add swagger to expose the APIs but when I installed Swashbuckle to the console project and configured Swagger in startup class, nothing can be found if I navigate to the swagger ui. It returns 401 error.

In ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddMvc
.AddApplicationPart(WebApi.GetAssembly()).AddControllersAsServices();
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1"});
});
```

In Configure method:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

I can invoke actions on the controller just fine, but seems like Swashbuckle hasn't generated any Swagger for it. Did I miss anything or it's not supported yet? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

While in am not using Swagger, in my context I had a similar problem, so I make sure to load the controllers manually:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection Services)
    {
        // find all controllers
        var Controllers =
            from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().AsParallel()
            from t in a.GetTypes()
            let attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ControllerAttribute), true)
            where attributes?.Length > 0
            select new { Type = t };

        var ControllersList = Controllers.ToList();
        Logging.Info($"Found {ControllersList.Count} controllers");

        // register them
        foreach (var Controller in ControllersList)
        {
            Logging.Info($"[Controller] Registering {Controller.Type.Name}");
            Services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(Options => Options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
                .AddApplicationPart(Controller.Type.Assembly);
        }
```

With this in the init, controllers get properly added and initialized

Answer (score 0):

I use Nswag for all my projects. I don't have much experience with Swashbuckle but they both serve similar purpose. I am providing a way to configure Nswag.

Add NSwag.AspNetCore nuget package to your project and in the startup class add the following code:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, settings =>
{
    settings.GeneratorSettings.DefaultPropertyNameHandling = PropertyNameHandling.CamelCase;

    settings.PostProcess = document =>
    {
        document.Info.Version = "v1";
        document.Info.Title = "RestAPI";
    };
});
```